# How to get my React Component Object from React Element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

On my first React component class (Window), I have:

```
constructor() {
  super();

  this.lines = {}; // Liste des cases (divs) de la fenêtre de jeu

  // Boucle création du squelette de la map (lignes puis colonnes)
  for (var row = 0; row < Constants.heightBL; row++) {
    this.lines[row] = <Line y={row} key={row}></Line>;
  }
}

render() {
  let elements = [];
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(this.lines)) {
    elements.push(value);
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.game} onMouseOver={this.handleMouseover}>
      {elements}
    </div>
  );
}

getLine(y) {
  return this.lines[y];
}

getBlock(x, y) {
  return this.getLine(y).blocks[x];
}

setCursor(x, y) {
  this.getBlock(x, y).setCursor(true);
  this.getBlock(Controller.cursor.x, Controller.cursor.y).setCursor(false);
}
```

On my second React component class (Line), I have:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.blocks = {};
}

initBlocks() {
  for (var col = 0; col < Constants.widthBL; col++) {
    this.blocks[col] = <Block x={col} y={this.props.y} key={col}></Block>;
  }
}

render() {
  this.initBlocks();

  let elements = [];
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(this.blocks)) {
    elements.push(value);
  }
  return (
    <div id={"line_" + this.props.y} className={styles.line}>
      {elements}
    </div>
  );
}

getBlock(x) {
  console.log(this.blocks);
  return this.blocks[x];
}

getBlocks() {
  return this.blocks;
}
```

And pn my third component (Block) I have this function:

```
setCursor(status) {
  this.setState({ isCursor: status });
}
```

So in Window I have a list of Lines and on each Line I have a list of Blocks, and I want to execute the setCursor function on my class Block from my class Window but blocks is undefined because `this.lines[y]` returns an element, not a instance of my class Line.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Why do you need access to the block component? You should probably flip this around and move all the state up to Window, then let Line and Block just render the result.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Because I would like to execute a function on a specific Block (which modifies the state of the Block) from the Window class @jonrsharpe

Comment: To what end? Please [edit] the question to give context. I'd also recommend having a look at https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html to get an idea of "the React way" to do things.

Comment: done @jonrsharpe